# Return an HTML element's HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This will output [object HTMLUListElement]:

```
ul = document.create('ul');
$('textarea').val(ul)
```

How do I get it to output `<ul></ul>`?

This will do the work but is there any way to get it directly from the html element object?

```
s = ul.wrap('<div></div>')
$('textarea').val(s.html())
```

Comment: Seems a rather round about way to get the markup, given that you already know the tag name of the element.

Answer (score 3):

Use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property of the element

```js
ul = document.createElement('ul');
$('textarea').val(ul.outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```